# Android permissions after submitting app to Amazon and Google

Tags: google-play, trigger.io, amazon-appstore, android-permissions

I recently submitted my app to both Amazon and Google.  I won't link to or mention the app at this time because I do not want you to think I am promoting it.  Rather I have **config.json** question related to permissions.  Here is a trimmed down version of my **config.json** -

```
"modules": {
    "contact": false,
    "event": true,
    "file": false,
    "geolocation": false,
    "is": true,
    "message": false,
    "notification": false,
    "prefs": false,
    "sms": false,
    "tabs": true,
    "tools": true,
    "topbar": true,
    "tabbar": true,
    "media": true
 }
```

After submitting my packaged .apk file... both Google & Amazon list the app's permissions.  Most of them make sense.  However, the ones listed below do **not** seem to make sense since I disabled file, contact, and geolocation in my json.config.

**Google** permissions indicate:

Your location - fine (GPS) location.

Your personal information - read contact data.

Storage - Allows the app to write to the USB storage. Allows the app to write to the SD card.

**Amazon** permissions indicate:

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

android.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

The "write external storage" permission is not a show stopper and I can live with it.  However, I do not want my potential users thinking that the app wants to access their geolocation and read their contacts... especially when Google displays -

> "Malicious apps may use this to determine where you are, and may consume additional battery power."
>
> "Allows the app to read all of the contact (address) data stored on your phone. Malicious apps may use this to send your data to other people."

Any idea what I am doing wrong in my config.json?  Maybe I should just leave geolocation & contact out?  Still... then setting these to false may not be working correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: I plan on submitting to Apple once Amazon approves.  Google published the app live within 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by exluding those redundant modules from the config.json instead of setting them to false.

Try this: (just removed the values contact, file and geolocation)

```
"modules": {
    "event": true,
    "is": true,
    "message": false,
    "notification": false,
    "prefs": false,
    "sms": false,
    "tabs": true,
    "tools": true,
    "topbar": true,
    "tabbar": true,
    "media": true
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick! We have a story to interpret `"module_name": false` as disabling that module in the pipeline too...

Comment: Thanks James as I rather have your fix, instead of removing modules.

Comment: Removed unnecessary modules from config.json and uploaded to Google Play this morning - required permissions look much much better... and less invasive.